# Cannot use height and width from img.shape for further calculations

Tags: python, opencv

I’m trying to split and image into multiple blocks using cv2.  My Problem is that `cv2.imread`, recognizes my height and width, but when I use these values to calculate x and y, my result is 0.

Also I get this error when I run the code:

> “slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method”
>   on this part of the code `img = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]`"

```
 import cv2
 import time

 img = cv2.imread('C:/Users/ML/Desktop/DataMatrix/Unbenannt.png')
 img2 = img

 height, width, channels = img.shape

 print (height, width, channels)
 CROP_W_SIZE  = 2 
 CROP_H_SIZE = 2

 for ih in range(CROP_H_SIZE ):
     for iw in range(CROP_W_SIZE ):

        x = width / CROP_W_SIZE * iw
        y = height / CROP_H_SIZE * ih
        h = (height / CROP_H_SIZE)
        w = (width / CROP_W_SIZE )

        print(x,y,h,w)

        img = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        NAME = str(time.time()) 
        cv2.imwrite("C:/Users/ML/Desktop/DataMatrix/CROP/" + str(time.time()) +  ".png",img)
        img = img2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to slap an `int()` function around those calculations of x, y, w, h. They're cast to floats when you divide.

Answer (score 1):

- The values of x and y appear to be 0 because in the first iteration of your loop, ih and iw takes value 0.
- The index error is due to in Python 3, the division is not integer division but it returns a floating number. You might like to use // instead.